# justify content won't align left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm practicing CSS/flexbox reproducing the login page of instagram but i'm facing a issue with horizontal alignment that i can't figure out what's wrong.

There's two major containers inside one big wrapper ("instagram-wraper" - each one get 50% of the width of that wraper).

- Container 1 (left): "cellphone-img" that contain only a cellphone img
- Container 2 (right): "account-info-container" that contain all the login inputs, subscribe, and so on.

The image on the left side work as intended, but what i'm trying to do is to align all the content in the account-info-container to the left with justify-content, essentially putting the image and the login containers side by side, but it doesn't work. What am i missing? (bet it's something simple...)

Thanks in advance.

PS: I didn't work on the responsiveness yet.

```css
/* General settings */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  font-size: 14px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  /* max-width: 1200px; */
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Wrapper img + wrapper login */

.instagram-wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 85vh;
}


/* Cellphone img container */

.cellphone-img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 50%;
  /* margin-left: 150px; */
}

.cellphone-img img {
  height: 630px;
  width: auto;
}


/* Login + subscribe + ap-downloads */

.account-info-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 50%;
  /* margin-right: 150px; */
}


/* Login wrapper */

.login-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 420px;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(var(--b6a, 219, 219, 219), 1);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.insta-logo {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 55px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}


/* Login inputs container */

.login {
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.login input {
  width: 85%;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: rgba(var(--b3f, 250, 250, 250), 1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(var(--ca6, 219, 219, 219), 1);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.input-login {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-password {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.login-btn {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: rgba(var(--d69, 0, 149, 246), 1);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.or-ruler {
  width: 85%;
  color: rgba(var(--f52, 142, 142, 142), 1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.or-ruler::before {
  content: "";
  width: 120px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(var(--ca6, 219, 219, 219), 1);
}

.or-ruler::after {
  content: "";
  width: 120px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(var(--ca6, 219, 219, 219), 1);
}

.facebook-login-btn {
  width: 85%;
  color: #385185;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.facebook-login-btn img {
  width: 17px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.forget-pass-link {
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #00376b;
}


/*  Subscribe container */

.subscribe {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(var(--b6a, 219, 219, 219), 1);
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.subscribe p a {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(var(--d69, 0, 149, 246), 1);
}


/* Apps download wrapper */

.app-download {
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
}

.app-imgs {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.app-imgs img {
  width: 170px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
}


/* Footer */

.footer-section {
  max-width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

footer div {
  margin: 8px auto;
}

footer a {
  margin: auto 10px;
  color: rgba(var(--f52, 142, 142, 142), 1);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="instagram-wrapper flex-container">
  <div class="cellphone-img">
    <img src="./images/instagram-celular2.png" alt="instagram cellphone" />
  </div>
  <div class="account-info-container">
    <div class="login-container flex-container">
      <div class="insta-logo">
        <img src="./images/instagram-logo.png" alt="instagram-logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="login flex-container">
        <input class="input-login" type="text" placeholder="Telefone, nome do usuário ou email" />
        <input class="input-password" type="text" placeholder="Senha" />
        <button class="login-btn">Entrar</button>
        <div class="or-ruler">
          <span> OU <span>
            </div>
            <button class="facebook-login-btn">
              <span><img src="./images/fb-icon.png" alt="" /></span>
          <span>Entrar com o Facebook</span>
          </button>

          <a class="forget-pass-link" href="">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="subscribe flex-container">
        <p>Não tem uma conta? <a href="">Cadastre-se</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="app-download flex-container">
        <p>Obtenha o aplicativo.</p>
        <div class="app-imgs">
          <a href="#"><img src="./images/apple-button.png" alt="appstore-img" /></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="./images/googleplay-button.png" alt="googleplay-img" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="footer-section">
    <footer>
      <div>
        <a href="">Meta</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
        <a href="">Jobs</a>
        <a href="">Help</a>
        <a href="">API</a>
        <a href="">Privacy</a>
        <a href="">Terms</a>
        <a href="">Top Accounts</a>
        <a href="">Hashtags</a>
        <a href="">Locations</a>
        <a href="">Instagram Lite</a>
        <a href=""> Contact Uploading & Non-Users</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="">Dance</a>
        <a href="">Food & Drink</a>
        <a href="">Home & Garden</a>
        <a href="">Music</a>
        <a href="">Visual Arts</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="">English</a>
        <a href="">© 2022 Instagram from Meta</a>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of your items inside the container are each 50% width, they won't move horizontally—they're spanning across the entire container; there's no free space (and `justify-content` works by distributing free space).

Remove the `width: 50%` rule and work on each item individually (using width, margin and/or flex properties).

Also, the `justify-content` property doesn't take `left` and `right` values. They're invalid. Here are the [values that work](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property).

Finally, when you're ready to pin both items to the left, [consider flex `auto` margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276).

Comment: Hey @Michael Benjamin. Tks for the answer! What i'm trying to move is the content of that container with width of 50%, not the container itself. Inside of the wrapper "account-info-container" there's four divs. It's those divs that i'm trying to align to the left of the container. I was experimenting the left and right and forgot to go back before sending. I eddited and fixed. Tks for pointing out. The flex-end works just fine on the left, but the flex-start doesn't work on the four divs on the right.

Comment: I only see three divs in that container (using dev tools inspector). But perhaps there's a missing closing`</div>` or something. The alignment problem is caused by the `margin: auto` on `.flex-container`. It keeps centering the content. Remove that and try something else.